# Presto: how to fill in gap and copy value from previous rows

Tags: presto

I have a table with 2 rows:

```
  Percent   Value  
 --------- ------- 
    99.95     230  
    99.92     130  
    99.05      94
```

I want to change this so that if there are gaps in the percent column (e.g. 99.94, 99.93, 99.91...), I want to create that row with the value from the previous row. so for example, 99.94 and 99.93 would have value of 130 and 99.91 would have value of 94.

Windowing function requires knowing fixed offset and also i don't think i can use it to populate new set of tables with more # of rows.

I think i can make it work by generating a number sequence table and cross join with this table, however, I don't know how to generate a dummy CTE with number sequence from 00.00 to 100.00 at 0.01 increment.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can generate the number sequence with: `select x/100.00 from unnest(sequence(1, 10000)) t(x);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suggested in your question, you can do it with a sequence table (by unnesting the output of the [`sequence`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) function) and the [`lag`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag) window function like this:

```sql
WITH data(p, v) AS (VALUES
    (99.95, 230),
    (99.92, 130),
    (99.05,  94)
),
sequence(p) AS (
    SELECT x/100.00 FROM unnest(sequence(1, 10000)) t(x)
)
SELECT
   sequence.p,
   coalesce(v, lag(v) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY sequence.p))
FROM data RIGHT JOIN sequence ON data.p = sequence.p
```